# Type Mismatch Run-Time error 13

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully run this macro before and now I am receiving a Mismatch error.

The macro copies all rows from a Data Tab (data-raw) where Col S = Cell D1 (on a different tab). Then pastes special values to a third tab (Rec01).

D1, formatted as General with Text data (name)
Col S, formatted as General, all formulas, displaying a name.

```
Sub CopyRowToRec01()
Dim LastRowData, LastRowRec01 As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LastRowData = Worksheets("data-raw-Comb").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Worksheets("data-raw-Comb")
    For i = 2 To LastRowData Step 1
        If Cells(i, "S").Value = Worksheets("data-lookuptable").Range("D1") Then
            LastRowRec01 = Worksheets("Rec01").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Rec01").Range("A" & LastRowRec01 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Running same version of Excel.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
DD

Comment: You are using `With`, but aren't connecting the ranges to the sheet.  Add `.` before `Cells()` when you're trying to reference the `data-raw-Comb` sheet with them.  Same with `Rows()`. Otherwise, they're going to use the activesheet which can cause issues.

Comment: Another note.... of the approx. 5k rows, it copies data up to a certain line, then stops. Example, I add on a monthly basis data, January dates, February dates, so forth... it works through May, but not June.

Comment: When you add data, is column A the one with the most info?

Comment: Yes, Col A is populated with data, all the way to the end. Continued getting the error after adding the "."

Comment: *Where* is the error?

Comment: data-raw-Comb = raw data being copied

Comment: data-lookuptable = just a reference sheet and Rec01 is where the data is pasted into

Comment: when I "debug" the type mismatch error, it highlights this row      If Cells(i, "S").Value = Worksheets("data-lookuptable").Range("D1") Then

Comment: @DruDreyer Did you see BruceWayne's comment from earlier? `Cells` is unqualified on that line - you need to add a `.` before it like he recommended.

Comment: I paste (append) new, raw data into data-raw-Comb, (jan, feb, mar, etc.) monthly. When I run the above code, only Jan through may copies to Rec01, not the newly pasted Jun data. it stops and gives the error.

Comment: @dwirony I added the period and get the same error. 'code'  If .Cells(i, "S").Value = Worksheets("data-lookuptable").Range("D1") Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If Cells(i, "S").Value = Worksheets("data-lookuptable").Range("D1") Then
```

Thank you every for your responses. I am not sure what changed from last time, but I had to change the `.Value` to `.Text`. Now it is running again, all data being pulled.

Sorry to bother.
Thanks again